# In eclipse cucumber feature file takes long time to build. Its bec

Tags: eclipse, build, cucumber

In eclipse cucumber build takes long time when making any changes to code. Is there any way to ensure faster build process time specially using eclipse cucumber automation in eclipse?
Basicaly any code change results in automatic build of the eclipse project in maven.

Tried to restart eclipse
Also tried to refresh project build

Expecting the auto build process to be faster and not take 30 mins

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic build process usually happens when making any changes to step definitions or cucumber feature files. To make it faster
Go to Eclipse -> windows -> preference
Scroll down till you see Cucumber, expand and click on java
Check mark "Use step definitions filters" and click on add filter
Whichever package your step definitions or glue code (code that creates method for "Given" "when" "then" feature file), give its package name

For example if your package name is com.org.stepdefinitions
then give com.org.stepdefinitions.*

Note:Even if these files are kept in src/test/java, no need to include this name in filter, only package name is required